# Best way to extract data from inconsistent xml C#/SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a temporary table in SQL Server 2016 which has many XML data. What I need is to get each XML, read the data from it to enter in another table and delete the data from temp table.
I have, however, two problems. One is the schema for XML is inconsistent. For some there could be extra node and for other it won't be there. Also for each XML, there are multiple messages on which I have to loop to create multiple rows for main table. Secondly, I have already tried to use 'CROSS APPLY' (I may had missed some joins but the data is coming anyway) and the result is taking 1 message per 20 seconds, tried SSIS (again missing 1-2 joins but data is coming anyway) and the result is taking 1 message per 8 seconds. Finally I created C# console code to get the message in datatable, convert it into XML document, checking whether node exists or not, making loop as required and finally inserting it into database again and it is taking around 3-4 messages per second.

Now my issue is, I want to make it faster(ideally 1000 messages per minute). Can anyone suggest any better way how to achieve this?

EDIT: (XML looks something like below)

```xml
<Step1>
  <MetaData>
    <Node1>Value</Node1>
    <Node2>Value</Node2>
  </MetaData>
  <ActualData>
    <MainNode>
      <Child1>
        <NodeA>Value</NodeA>
      </Child1>
      <Child2>
        <Numbers>
          <Child a="b">LoopValue</Child>
          <Optional a="b">AdditionalLoopValue</Optional>
        </Numbers>
        <Alphabets>
          <Child a="b">
            <Child1>
              <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
              <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
            </Child1>
            <Child2>
              <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
              <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
            </Child2>
          </Child>
          <Optional a="b">
            <Child1>
              <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
              <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
            </Child1>
            <Child2>
              <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
              <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
            </Child2>
          </Optional>
        </Alphabets>
      </Child2>
      <Child3>
        <Loop1>
          <Child1>Value</Child1>
          <Child2>
            <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
          </Child2>
          <Child3>
            <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
            <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
          </Child3>
          <Child4>Value</Child4>
        </Loop1>
        <Loop2>
          <Child1>Value</Child1>
          <Child2>
            <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
          </Child2>
          <Child3>
            <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
            <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
          </Child3>
          <Child4>Value</Child4>
          <Optional1>
            <Sub1>Value</Sub1>
            <Sub2>Value</Sub2>
          </Optional1>
        </Loop2>
      </Child3>
    </MainNode>
  </ActualData>
</Step1>
```

EDIT 2: (Code looks something like below)

```
string a,b,c;
DataTable dt;
foreach on DataTable.Rows
{    foreach node on nodelist
     {   if Node1.ChildNode !=null
            {a=Node1.ChildNode["NodeName"]}
        if Node1.ChildNode !=null
            {b=Node1.ChildNode["NodeName"]}
        for loop on b
            {if Node1.ChildNode != null
                {c=Node1.ChildNode["NodeName"]}
            dt.Rows.Add(a,b,c);}}
    delete from temp table based on id.
    add records from dt to main table
    dt.Rows.Clear();}
```

Comment: Your final approach seems reasonable (although I wonder why you put it in a data table first - get it as string and parsing it might be faster. Note that an optional node is not inconsistent XML, it's very standard. Without actual code, we cannot see what is taking up the processing time, so please show us what you have tried (the last approach seems ok...)

Comment: Because I have to bring other columns as well which is why i put it in a datatable. I have made the edits to include samples of xml and code algorithm. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string str { get; private set; }

private void RecursiveSearchInXmlWithString(XmlNode xmlnode, string nametofind)
    {
        // check if node has children, if so then it recursively search the children too
        if (xmlnode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                RecursiveSearchInXmlWithString(xmlnode.ChildNodes[i], nametofind);
            }
        }
        // here is the element that we are searching for 
        if (xmlnode.Name == nametofind)
        {
            str = xmlnode.InnerText;
        }
    }
```

I have resursive function with a public global variable for this class. Only the correct value will be catch by str, you can use str after calling it. After every node, you have to catch str. You can figure it out after this.

You also need to handle every possible situation with if statements.

Comment: Using recursion in my case will not be good even if I put break to end the loop, it will still slow down. I atleast know where the optional node could appear so I had already put all the necessary ifs.
I am open to any method to make its performance faster than the current performance.

Answer (score 0):

If these XMLs are big and you have a lot of them it will need a lot of time to shift the data into your C# application and create an XML document in order to read this. If the column is a native XML column it will be much faster to keep this work done within SQL-Server.

Your XML is deeply nested. I hope, that you can rely on some structure to be the same in any case.

Just a hint how you might proceed:

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/Step1/MetaData/Node1/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Meta1
      ,@xml.value(N'(/Step1/MetaData/Node2/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Meta2
      ,childNode.value(N'local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ChildNode

      ,lvl2Numbers.value(N'(Child/@a)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NumberChildA
      ,lvl2Numbers.value(N'(Child/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NumberChildText
      ,lvl2Numbers.value(N'(Optional/@a)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NumberOptionalA
      ,lvl2Numbers.value(N'(Optional/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NumberOptionalText

      ,lvl2Alpha.query(N'.') AS lvl2Alpha
      --add further levels here

      ,lvl2Loop.query(N'.') AS lvl2Loop
      --add further levels here
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Step1/ActualData/MainNode/*') AS A(childNode)

OUTER APPLY childNode.nodes(N'*[local-name()="Numbers"]') AS B1(lvl2Numbers)

OUTER APPLY childNode.nodes(N'*[local-name()="Alphabets"]') AS B2(lvl2Alpha)
OUTER APPLY lvl2Alpha.nodes(N'Child') AS B2a(ChildrenOfAlpha)
OUTER APPLY ChildrenOfAlpha.nodes(N'*') AS B2aa(SubChildrenOfAlpha)
OUTER APPLY SubChildrenOfAlpha.nodes(N'*') AS B2ab(SubsInSubChildrenOfAlpha)
OUTER APPLY lvl2Alpha.nodes(N'Optional') AS B2b(OptionalOfAlpha)
OUTER APPLY OptionalOfAlpha.nodes(N'*') AS B2ba(SubOptionalOfAlpha)
OUTER APPLY SubOptionalOfAlpha.nodes(N'*') AS B2bb(SubsInSubOptionalOfAlpha)

OUTER APPLY childNode.nodes(N'*[substring(local-name(),1,4)="Loop"]') AS B3(lvl2Loop)
--and so on
```

With a query like this you can step down the hierarchy and get back the *whole everything* in a denormalized broad table. But this won't be fast...

I'd create a query for each kind of data structure and use either `T-SQL` for the logic, or use a `.query()` call and load this result into C# to deal with a small fragment there.

### Hint

If the construction of this XML is under your control try to avoid *name-numbered* elements (`<Child1>, <Child2> ...`) If you need this, change it to `<Child nr="1">, <Child nr="2"> ...` - much better and faster to read...

Comment: The construction of this xml is not in my control otherwise i'll put some sense in this xml :( I am only getting xml from a server and storing it as it is in table and requirement is to break this xml so I could put some filters to view the records.
As mentioned in my question, I had made the query much similar to your, the only difference was I used 'CROSS APPLY' in that and yes I am 'getting back whole everything in a denormalized broad table' which was the actual requirement.
But the issue was it was extremely slow while I want to speed up the process.

Comment: @Zuberi, XML's `.exist()` works pretty fast... If I understand you correctly, you know quite well, what to expect within one XML at which place. These XMLs are deeply nested... Shredding them into tables will need some time. But this is a *one-time-action*, isn't it? You might use `.exist()` to get bunches of XMLs with certain structures and shred them into persistant tables with a more light weight (more specific) approach.